# Read a sql hierarchy into a c# object

Tags: c#, sql, tree, hierarchy

How would you read the SQL data to get a hierarchical list of units?

WITHOUT depending on a SQL Server only solution?

```
public class Unit {
    public Unit Parent { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

List<Unit> list = new List<Unit>();

while(reader.Read())
{
    // read sql data into clr object UNIT
}
```

The table has 3 columns:

```
Id| ParentId | Name
1 | Null     | bla
2 |   1      | x
3 |   1      | y
4 |   2      | z
5 |   2      | test
```

**UPDATE**:

```
That is the code which is taken from user marc_s:

 List<Unit> units = new List<Unit>();

            String commandText =
            @";WITH Hierarchy AS
              (
                 SELECT
                    ID,  ParentID = CAST(NULL AS INT),
                    Name, HierLevel = 1
                 FROM
                    dbo.Unit
                 WHERE
                    ParentID IS NULL

                 UNION ALL

                 SELECT
                    ht.ID, ht.ParentID, ht.Name, h1.HierLevel + 1
                 FROM
                    dbo.Unit ht
                 INNER JOIN 
                    Hierarchy h1 ON ht.ParentID = h1.ID
              )
              SELECT Id, ParentId, Name
              FROM Hierarchy
              ORDER BY HierLevel, Id";

            using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
            {
                con.Open();

                // use SqlDataReader to iterate over results
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        // get the info from the reader into the "Unit" object
                        Unit thisUnit = new Unit();

                        thisUnit.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                        thisUnit.UnitName = rdr["Name"].ToString();                     

                        // check if we have a parent
                        if (rdr["ParentId"] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            // get ParentId
                            int parentId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ParentId"]);

                            // find parent in list of units already loaded
                            // NOTE => not needed anymore => Unit parent = units.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == parentId);

                            // Instead use this method to find the parent:


                            Unit parent = FindParentUnit(units, parentId);

                            // if parent found - set this unit's parent to that object
                            if (parent != null)
                            {
                                thisUnit.Parent = parent;
                                parent.Children.Add(thisUnit);
                            }
                        }
                       else
                       {
                           units.Add(thisUnit);
                       }
                    }
                }
            }

            return units;
```

Thats a screenshot of the populated List

http://oi41.tinypic.com/rmpe8n.jpg

Thats the sql data from the Unit table:

http://oi40.tinypic.com/mt12sh.jpg

**QUESTION**:

Actually the  populated List should have only ONE Unit object not 11 (Index 0 - 10). Yes the first Unit in the List is populated correctly, but the units Index 1 - 10 should not be in the list.

This is how it should look like actually:

```
0
|--1
|   |--3
|   |   |--9
|   |   |--10  
|   |--4
|--2
|   |--5
|   |--6
|--7
|--8
```

UPDATE and SOLUTiON

```
private static Unit FindParentUnit(List<Unit> units, int parentId)
        {
            Unit parent;
            foreach (Unit u in units)
            {
                if (u.Id == parentId){
                    return u;                                    
                }
                parent = FindParentUnit(u.Children, parentId);
                if (parent != null)
                    return parent;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037501/sql-data-hierarchy?

Comment: See [Wikipedia ON CTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions): *Common table expressions are supported by DB2, Firebird [1], Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, HyperSQL and H2 (experimental)*

Comment: OK - so what's the problem?? Your "root" person (ID=0) has **four children** - as would be expected from the data you provided. I'm pretty sure if you drill down into that root person's "Children" collection, you'll find the other nodes and their children, too.

Comment: If you don't want to put all the nodes into the list - just don't do it!! :-) So after the `if (rdr["ParentId"] != DBNull.Value)`, have an `else { .... } ` clause and put the statement `units.Add(thisUnit);` into that else clause - then **only** those units with no parent will be stuck into the list.... Updated my answer accordingly.....

Comment: Actually afair i already did that when i said i corrected your code, hmm thats odd why did it not work then? Just see the revisions it should be there. Ok i gotta check it again.

Comment: "...I'm pretty sure if you drill down into that root person's "Children" collection, you'll find the other nodes and their children, too". No I do NOT and I did not. There is one unit in the list with 4 children units but NONE of the children units has any children unit like Id 3 or 4 which should be children of Unit with Id 1. I just put the Else{ units.Add(unit)} at the correct place like I did before... Any idea?

Comment: Unit parent = units.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == parentId); the parent for Id 3 or Id 4 IS ParentId 1 which is not in the units list on the root level but inside the children property of the unit with Id 1. Probably a Linq SelectMany helps that would not be  performant...  And yes your original version where the list had 11 unit object should work with the units.FirstOrDefault search, but I want only one Unit in the list as its a hierarchy bound to a control which would look silly seeing all units...

Comment: and copy the root unit having all other units from this flat list to a new list before it gets bound to a control sounds stupid.

Comment: I have updated the init post with some code corrections and a recursive search for a parent unit. NOW it works :) I will still mark your "engagement" as solution.

Comment: @Pascal: OK, glad you could make it work after all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it :-)

```
// set up connection string
string connectionString = "server=.;database=test;integrated Security=SSPI;";

// define a CTE (Common Table Expression) to recursively build your hierarchical
// structure into a flat list and order it according to its "sequence" (root first)
string cteStatement =
            @";WITH Hierarchy AS
              (
                 SELECT
                    ID,  ParentID = CAST(NULL AS INT),
                    Name, HierLevel = 1
                 FROM
                    dbo.HierarchyTest   -- replace with your table name!
                 WHERE
                    ParentID IS NULL

                 UNION ALL

                 SELECT
                    ht.ID, ht.ParentID, ht.Name, h1.HierLevel + 1
                 FROM
                    dbo.HierarchyTest ht   -- replace with your table name!
                 INNER JOIN 
                    Hierarchy h1 ON ht.ParentID = h1.ID
              )
              SELECT Id, ParentId, Name
              FROM Hierarchy
              ORDER BY HierLevel, Id";

// set up list of "Unit" objects
List<Unit> units = new List<Unit>();

// create connection and command to query             
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cteStatement, conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    // use SqlDataReader to iterate over results
    using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
            // get the info from the reader into the "Unit" object
            Unit thisUnit = new Unit();

            thisUnit.Id = rdr.GetInt32(0);
            thisUnit.Name = rdr.GetString(2);
            thisUnit.Children = new List<Unit>();

            // check if we have a parent
            if(!rdr.IsDBNull(1))
            {
                // get ParentId
                int parentId = rdr.GetInt32(1);

                // find parent in list of units already loaded
                Unit parent = units.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == parentId);

                // if parent found - set this unit's parent to that object
                if(parent != null)
                {
                    thisUnit.Parent = parent;
                    parent.Children.Add(thisUnit);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                units.Add(thisUnit);
            }
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Does that work for you??

The CTE (Common Table Expression) recursively scans your table and builds up a list of hierarchical nodes - by sorting it by the "hierarchy level", you can make sure to get all the parent nodes, before their child nodes show up (so that the code works)

**Update:** Ok so it seems you want to put **only** nodes with **no parent** into the resulting list - that's fine (but you didn't really say you wanted to have it that way!!) - I updated my code above - please re-check again!!

Comment: I edited my question: please ms sql server independend solution :)

Comment: @Pascal: CTE **IS** a part of the ANSI SQL-99 Standard - it is **NOT** SQL Server specific!

Comment: you do a conn.Close() in a USING statement?

Comment: @Pascal: yes - it doesn't hurt - and that way, it's clear what I want to do. I like to be explicit rather than relying on "magic" effects ... (those are great for backup - but don't start to rely on them...)

Comment: well the sole purpose of USING is to free me from that burden and dispose of all resources. But I am sure you know that already and its all about my init question here not your coding styling, the close was just flashing in my eyes ;-)

Comment: grrr.. I forgot to mention in my Unit class there is still a Children property of type List<Unit>... if you still read this ;-) How would you populate this property?

Comment: @Pascal: added two lines of code to my answer - first one when you create a new `Unit` - make sure to create the `Children` collection, too. Second line is when you set the parent of a newly created `Unit` - you can also add that newly created unit to parent's collection of children

Comment: Thank you Mark. I have still a last question: Where is the difference with your CTE-solution compared to a normal Select query and the rows are ordered ascending by the Id of the Unit?

Comment: @Pascal: the recursive CTE order the rows by the hierarchy they're defined in - it gives you that extra information. If you had a structure where a parent node might have been inserted later, with a higher ID - it would end up coming out in the wrong order if you order just by ID - no?

Comment: Yes.  The node would be at the wrong position if its id is set by a sql identity column. Thank you.

Comment: I corrected the C# code so that the List<Unit> is populated correctly :)

Comment: somehow the C# code to populate the list works only for a hierarchy with one level. That means my units has One Unit with another 4 Units in its Children Property. But those 4 units has no units in their children property ??

Comment: @Pascal: this statement of yours is totally wrong - that code of mine **works just fine** even for 4 or 5 levels of hierarchy - I just verified it **again**. Either your data is not as it should be, or you've modified this code in some way that broke it :-)

Comment: OK I recheck again and you get the solution than of course! Thanks for checking that too.

Comment: I updated my init question with sample code/images why it does not work fine. Please check that, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use an Object Relational Mapper, such as entity framework to do the work for you. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6064735/113683) to a similar sounding EF question should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your data represent a tree structure, you only need to construct the tree creating the root Unit and adding the leaves. You can use a Dictionary instead of the List for seacrhing in the tree, this is simple to do.
Here an example that works only if the rows are ordered ascending by id:

```
Dictionary<Int32,Unit> dic = new Dictionary<Int32,Unit>();

while(reader.Read()) 
{ 
    //create the new Unit
    // if the parent is not null get the parent unit from dic
    // add the new Unit to dic
}
```

Comment: You are a bit unclear. Is that what you meant? Unit unit = new Unit();
If(!DB.IsNull(reader[„parentId“])){
   Unit parent = dic[ Convert.ToInt32(reader[„parentId“]) ];
   Dic.Add(unit.Id,unit);
}